# Typescript generic object mapping with a mapper object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a generic object mapping function that would allow me for example to map an entity object to a data transfer object. The rules for the mapping would be given in a mapper object.

For example, with the following,

```js
class UserEntity {
  id: number
  userName: string
}
class CustomerDto {
  customerNumber: number
  name: string
  slug: string
}
const mapper = {
  customerNumber: 'id',
  name: 'userName',
  slug: (userEntity: UserEntity) => (
    userEntity.userName.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '-')
  )
}
```

the property `id` of `UserEntity` would be mapped to `customerNumber` on `Customer`, `userName` to `name` and the property `slug` would be set using the given function.

Here's my code:

```js
type FilteredKeys<T, U> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends U ? P : never
}[keyof T]

type Mapper<S, D> = {
  [DK in keyof D]?: ( FilteredKeys<S, D[DK]> ) | ( (source: S) => D[DK] ) 
}

function map<S, D>(
  source: S,
  mapper: Mapper<S, D>
) {
  const destination: D = {} as D
  for (const key in mapper) {
    const val = mapper[key]
    if (typeof val === 'function') {
      destination[key] = val(source)
    } else if (typeof val !== 'undefined') {
      destination[key] = source[val]
    }
  }
  return destination
}
```

Full example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-p3d9zu)

There are at least two type issues that I'm not sure how to solve:

- The mapper object property values cannot be used as keys for the source object.
- The type guarding is apparently not sufficient.

A simplified version ( [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bkqvjx) ) that only supports functions in the mapper seems to work:

```js
type Mapper<S, D> = {
  [DK in keyof D]?: (source: S) => D[DK]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use type guards and assert the type like this

```
function isFunction(val: any): val is () => string {
  return typeof val === "function";
}

function isUndefined(val: any): val is string {
  return typeof val !== "undefined";
}
```

and use it like this

```
function map<S, D>(source: S & { [key: string]: any }, mapper: Mapper<S, D>) {
  const destination: any = {};
  for (const key in mapper) {
    const val = mapper[key];
    if (isFunction(val)) {
      destination[key] = val(source);
    } else if (isUndefined(val)) {
      destination[key] = source[val];
    }
  }
  return destination;
}
```